# Save and Play DRM secured audio file in ios

Tags: ios, audio, drm

I am developing music iOS app in which I am fetching audio file from server in bytes format and save in device in mp3 format. So when I am going to play audio file it is working fine. In some cases Audio file is DRM secured on server. I have one password but don't know how to use it.

My question is how to save and play DRM secured file?

Comment: May I know what is the music server? Because different server provide different DRM protection solution, such as PlayReader, OMA DRM,  Widevine etc. And you mean you have a password or the key to decrypt the music file?